# sum up an array in the special style of reduction | (i * 2)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sum, reduction

I am currently sitting on a java problem I've found online.

---

We have an array which has several thousand, if not millions, of entries.
the goal is to efficiently get the full sum of the array.

The first way is to simply sum the values up. This is how I've solved it:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) sum += array[i];
```

The other way is the hard way. In the online task, it is described to use some kind of reduction. you should add up all the neighboring elements, then add up every second, then every fourth and so on. Until you arrive at [0] + [max] at the end, [0] has the total sum of the array.

If someone could help me or steer me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

---

EDIT:

I solved it.

```java
int i = 1;
while (i <= array_size) {

    for (int j = 0; j < array_size - i; j += i) {

        x[j] += x[j + i];

    }

    i *= 2;
}
```

<strike>With this code it would then be possible to parallelize the process.</strike> thanks @mtj!

Hope it helps sometime someone else...

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the array's elements? If not, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by overcomplicating a simple summation - could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: What is the purpose? Reducing space complexity? Time complexity? Both?

Comment: Your implementation is already O(n)-time  you cannot get better. You need O(1)-Space, so this will also not be able to be reduced. You only could try to improve runtime (not  complexity) e.g. by make it more cache frindly.

Comment: Your "solution" does nothing supporting parallelism. If you really want to multi-thread, simply use `Arrays.stream(x).parallel().sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is already **O(n)-time**  you cannot get better. You need **O(1)-space**, so this will also not be able to be reduced.

You only could try to improve runtime (not  complexity) e.g. by make it more cache friendly or paralize it in hope that this may improve the speed (but for such a simple tasks as adding, I assume that memory-access is a bottle neck).